# Is there a way to switch between obtained scorestreaks?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

In Black Ops 2, if I get multiple scorestreaks in a single match, am I allowed to switch between them and choose which one I want?

For example, say I've obtained UAV, and then a Care Package.  Is there a way I can use the UAV before the care package?

The console I am using is the Xbox 360, but if you know the answer for other consoles as well, please include them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can press down or up on the D-Pad to cycle through your scorestreaks.  Whichever one is highlighted in the scorestreak list is the one you will use next.

If you get an item via a care package, it will be in a fourth slot at the top of the list.  Otherwise, they will be in the order they are unlocked.

Whichever one you've unlocked most recently is the one that will be used by default.